# Printing from command line

Tags: command-line, bash, printing

Please can anybody explain what exactly these commands and options do:

```
find /home/mike/Duck/ -type f -iname '*.txt' -print 0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f;
 do lpr "$f" && mv "$f" /home/mike/Duck/printed/ ; done
```

and what if i want to print all extension in that directory what should i do ?

Answer (score 4):

The code snippet you have given requires a modification, you need `-print0` instead of `print 0`.

This script will find (`find`) all the files having extension `txt` in `/home/mike/Duck/`, send them to printer (`lpr`) one at a time and then if that returns a success (`&&`) then the file will be moved (`mv`) to `/home/mike/Duck/printed/`.

If you want to print files having any extensions, use this:

```
find /home/mike/Duck/ -type f -name '*.*' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f;
 do lpr "$f" && mv -i "$f" /home/mike/Duck/printed/ ; done
```

This assumes that all files having extensions are in the format `file.ext`, it will also print the files having multiple dots. The `-i` with `mv` will give you a prompt before overwriting.

Also note that this can be done using only `find`:

```
find /home/mike/Duck/ -type f -name '*.*' -exec lpr {} \; -exec mv -i {} /home/mike/Duck/printed/ \;
```

Comment: I don't think it's the use of `read -d ''` that removes the need to unset IFS, is it? rather, it is because bash's `read` slurps "leftover words and their intervening separators" into the last (in this case, the only) variable.

Comment: @steeldriver For some weird reason, I thought `-d` will take precedence over `IFS` rather than only the newline (as I have checked now)..modifying..

Comment: I think the purpose of  `-i` to overwrite the file , if the file has been previously printed

Comment: @Serg Its other way around actually.. `mv -i` will give you a prompt if a file having same name already exists..

Comment: @heemayl ah, right. Because the script clears the Duck folder of printed files and moves them to printed.